# Remove leading zeros month and day values in a mm-dd-yyyy formatted date string

Tags: php, date, date-conversion, leading-zero

What would I change to make this format without leading zeros? I know it is simple but have not worked with PHP in some time.

```
$ts = strtotime($product['releaseDate']);
$release_date_formatted = date('m-d-Y', $ts);

Release Date
03-01-2020 --> 3-1-2020
08-15-2020 --> 8-15-2020
04-09-2018 --> 4-9-2020
```

Comment: `$str = substr($str, 1);`

Comment: Change the `date` parameters to the non-padded variants. https://php.net/date

Answer (score 0):

```
date('n-d-Y')
```

Check out this [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), which contains a detailed description:

"n" stand for: Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros.